# How do I override the default tabindent for Ruby in Vim?

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation

I'm using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) for vim and am really liking it, but I can't seem to get my preferred tabstop of 4 working right. This is in my `.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
```

Later on I have

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

But all of my ruby files keep using the default version of 2, which I just don't like. I've tried following the instructions on [this page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code), including creating a `ruby.vim` file in the after folder (and in the `indent` folder that janus created). I've added:

```
au FileType ruby set softtabstop=4 tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

to my .vimrc, but none of those work.

I can manually call `set tabstop`, etc from command mode, which works, but that's not a great solution.

What's missing?

Comment: try setting the tab stuff after `filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Can you try `:verbose set tabstop sw softtabstop expandtab ?`. It should tell which script is modifying your value of 4.

Comment: Xavier T. That worked! It told me that there was an `autoload/rails.vim` file setting those. Opened it up and changed the values to 4. If you want to add that as a real answer below, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xavier T's comment provided the answer, but since he didn't actually make an answer, here it is:

> Can you try :verbose set tabstop sw softtabstop expandtab ?. It should tell which script is modifying your value of 4.

This lead me to see that `autoload/rails.vim` was what was setting the tab spacing back.

Answer (score 1):

As per (at least the current version) of Janus ..

The preferred way to override settings is to edit ~/.vimrc.after

This file gets loaded after all of Janus stuff and whatever you put in there should override any settings set elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, that setting is found in tpope's ruby/rails plugin. I'm not sure, but if you try to set your tab settings at the end of .vimrc, they should work.

also, give a check at .gvimrc, especially if you're using macvim/gvim

Answer (score 0):

Once you are inside vim, run :set tabstop and it will show you what it was last set to. If this is different from what you expect it means that it is being overwritten. To debug, use find or ack (my personal favourite) to find all files that have the word tabstop. A good place to start is inside your .vimrc folder and run ack -l tabstop.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/richoH/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

Lines 141-160.

It's a fairly crude approach, originally it did a few other things. It needs refactoring, but this ought to give you enough to go with.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file `~/.vimrc.after`

within the file, set tab to 4 spaces `set tabstop=4`

Then janus will load the .vimrc.after file after janus